# Reuse Credential for Sign in with Apple in Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

After reading in the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/yahoo-oauth?hl=it#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors) how to manage account errors with the same email but different credentials I modified my code as the Firebase documentation recommends but I'm still finding problems

When authentication with Facebook encounters the `AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue` error, it obtains a **temporary credential** (it can occur in `(error! As NSError) .userInfo [AuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey]`)

then search within Firebase for the providers that the user has used up to now with the `Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods`

When it meets (in my example) the provider **"apple.com"**, the documentation says to **authenticate** the user and make (if all goes well) the link with the provider using the **temporary credential** obtained.

Now my problem is that when **Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods** meets the provider **"apple.com"** I can't authenticate with this provider because apple credentials can only be used once ... So at this point I wonder how I get out of this situation?

If we follow the documentation it says to authenticate with **EmailAuthProviderID** but obviously I think this is just an example .. in the documentation I think that instead of having met (as in my case) the provider **"apple.com"** met **EmailAuthProviderID** ...

---

Am I wrong with this interpretation of the documentation?

Am I making other mistakes and not realizing it?

Can a Facebook account not be linked to an existing Apple account?

---

Sorry but I have been banging my head on this problem for days ..

**This is the updated code**

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: authToken)) { authResult, error in
    if error != nil {
      // Handle error.
        if (error as NSError?)?.code == AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue {
            // Get pending credential and email of existing account.
            let existingAcctEmail = (error! as NSError).userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey] as! String
            let pendingCred = (error! as NSError).userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey] as! AuthCredential

            Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: existingAcctEmail) { (methods, error) in

                if (methods?.contains("apple.com"))! {

                    // **** This Flow stops here because I can't reuse Apple's credentials a second time. *****

                    let tokenID = KeychainManager.getItemFromKeychain(forKey: AuthKey.applTokenID, keyPrefix: AuthKey.prefix)!
                    let nonce = KeychainManager.getItemFromKeychain(forKey: AuthKey.applNonce, keyPrefix: AuthKey.prefix)

                    let appleCredentials = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", accessToken: tokenID)


                    Auth.auth().signIn(with: appleCredentials) { user, error in
                        if user != nil {
                          // Link pending credential to account.
                          Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: pendingCred) { result, error in
                            // ...
                            print("\n LINK")

                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            print(error!)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think the `ASAuthorization` delegate gives us new credentials and you are using one already saved from the keychain.

Comment: @Rob Yes, in fact, I wanted to understand how to solve this because using the ones saved in the keychain I always get the same error Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential.

Comment: Yeah, my point is the same. I'm using the delegate method to get the new token to create the new credential. I am not saving them in `keychain` or `userdefaults` and using them later on.I'm always requesting new one and using them in the `fetchProvider` method and I get new `credentials` via `OAuth` and there is no error for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209590/discussion-between-rob-and-kain).

Answer (score 3):

*This is the solution that I have adopted .. Obviously it must be customized according to the functioning of your App*

---

So far I have solved asking the user to log in with the existing provider. When the user logs in with the **existing provider**, he creates the connection with the chosen provider .

I explain ...

If the user wants to log in with **Apple** and an account with **Google already exists**, the code should be set in this way to be sure that the user really wants to connect the two providers:

1. in the delegated method of **AutenticationService** `didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization:` **(if the user logs in with apple for the first time**) check with **Auth.auth (). FetchSignInMethods** which providers already exist with his email retrieved from his appleID information

---

**Note**:

Apple's user data is provided only on its first access. For all other accesses with Sign in With Apple the user data will not be provided

---

2. If there are no providers associated with the user's email, complete the authentication flow

   **2.1**. If there are existing providers with the same email (for example **GOOGLE**), first of all we show a notice that informs the user which providers are associated with his email *(previous authentications with other providers)* then we allow the user to choose with which provider (*in this case **GOOGLE***) wants to log in to connect **Apple**.

   **2.2** When the user chooses the provider (**GOOGLE**) with which to connect **Apple** we recall the authentication flow of the existing provider (as if the user was pushing the **GOOGLE** **button**).

At this point with the authentication flow included (in our case **Google**) and if everything is successful, we call `Auth.auth (). CurrentUser.link (with: credential)` with Apple credentials

---

**Note:**

In all this, Apple's credentials were saved inside the Keychain when the user pushed the button and deleted immediately after the link with the existing provider

*Apple credentials cannot be reused once used*

---

Answer (score 1):

So, this is the solution that I've always worked with and it is mentioned in the `Firebase` Documentation itself. First of all, you need to understand the concept of linking `Multiple Auth Providers`. I'm trying to be as elaborative as possible as a lot of you are facing this issue. `Firebase` is owned by `Google` and every time you sign in with `Google` it automatically overrides the other sign-in methods like `Apple Sign In`, `Facebook`, `Google`.

So, to solve that use the `Google Sign In` button. I'm keeping my answer generic even the `Javascript` developers can follow this as I've done the same thing in `JS` as well.

You have to get the `email` from `Google` and every provider like `FB, Apple` etc. Then you have to use this method: `fetchSignInMethods`.

```
func fetchSignInMethods(provider: String, email: String) {
 Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email) { (providers, error) in
   if let error = error {
    print(error)
    return 
   } 

   let matched = providers?.filter{ $0 == provider }.count //Here I check if the provider I sent example `Facebook` and the fetched provider are same or not, if it is matched then I can go ahead and login the user directly else I have to show them linking alert as already this email exists with different sign in methods

  if providers?.isEmpty || matched == 1 {
            var credential: AuthCredential!

            switch provider {

            case Constants.LoginProviders.Google.rawValue: //google.com

                credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,accessToken: token) //idToken and AccessToken are fetched from Google Sign In Button

            default: //facebook.com

                credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token) //AccessToken is fetched from Facebook Sign In Button

                break
            }

            self.loginWithCredential(credentail: credential, provider: provider)
  } //I am also checking if provider is empty then I can sign them up for Email and Password users using Auth.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword 
  else {
      self.displayLinkingAlert(provider: fetchedProviderName)
  }
 } 
}

    //This function is used to display the alert when an account needs to be linked
//Provider is the parameter which will be fetched from LoginProviders(Constants.swift)

private func displayLinkingAlert(provider: String) {

     MKProgress.hide()

    let providerName = getProviderName(provider: provider)

    let alertC: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Link Accounts?", message: "This account is already linked with \(providerName). Do you want to link accounts?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let linkAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Link account with \(providerName)", style: .default) { (_) in

        self.linkAccounts.toggle() //Toggle linkAccounts to true to link the accounts of user

        switch provider {

        case Constants.LoginProviders.Google.rawValue:

            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()

            break

        default: self.facebookLoginWithPermissions(from: LoginViewController())

        }
    }

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let actions: [UIAlertAction] = [linkAction, cancelAction]

    actions.forEach{ alertC.addAction($0) }

    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(alertC, animated: true, completion: nil)

} //I also too a private var linkAccounts = false above in the class

//This function is used to get the providerName from the provider
//Ex.:- provider -> google.com, providerName: Google

private func getProviderName(provider: String) -> String
{
    var providerName = ""

    switch provider
    {
    case Constants.LoginProviders.Email.rawValue : providerName = "Email"

    case Constants.LoginProviders.Facebook.rawValue : providerName = "Facebook"

    case Constants.LoginProviders.Google.rawValue : providerName = "Google"

    default: break

    }

    return providerName
}
```

Now, this will show you the linking alert. Well, it is up to you how you want to proceed. In my apps, I've `Google`, `Facebook` and `Email` sign in methods enabled and I show the users both of them in case if two providers are fetched from `Firebase`. For eg.

If I have already signed up with `Google` and `Facebook`, then if I try to sign the user up with email it will show me two alert buttons `Link With Google` and `Link With Facebook`. Now, it is up to you if you want you can show them both or you can just them one, I can even add `Apple Sign In` here, it's up to individual's choice.

Now, when the alert appears and you press the `Link With Facebook` option firstly it will `toggle` the `linkAccount` variable to true and then, it will call the `facebookTap` method which will again `fetch` the `providers` like this:

```
private func facebookTap() {
   //Get the details and get the email then...

   fetchSignInMethods(provider: Constants.LoginProviders.Facebook.rawValue //facebook.com, email: emailFetched) //This will sign in the user using Facebook and as the linkAccount variable is true it will link ther user
}

//A common function used to login the users, by using their credentails
//Parameter credential is of type AuthCredential which is used to
//signInAndRetrieve data of a particular user.

func loginWithCredential(credentail: AuthCredential, provider: String) {

    authInstance.signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentail) { [unowned self](authResult, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {

            if self.linkAccounts {

                var loginCredential: AuthCredential!

                switch provider {
                case Constants.LoginProviders.Google.rawValue:
                    guard let facebookTokenString = AccessToken.current?.tokenString else { return }

                    loginCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: facebookTokenString)

                    break

                default:

                    loginCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: self.googleIdToken, accessToken: self.googleAccessToken)

                    break
                }

                self.linkAccounts(credential: loginCredential)

            } else {

                self.getFirebaseToken()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am using this to `link` accounts:

```
//This function is used to link the Accounts
//Ex:- Google with Facebook, vice-versa

private func linkAccounts(credential: AuthCredential) {

    authInstance.currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { (authResult, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)

            return

        } else {

            self.linkAccounts.toggle() //Toggle Link Account to false as acccounts are already linked

            //Navigate user to another page or do your stuff 

        }
    })

}
```

Now, this is the solution that I tried and it worked for me everytime. It worked for me in `Swift`, `Flutter`, `Javascript` and it will work with every other language. You can do the same thing with `Apple Sign In Button`. In the delegate where you get the details if user shared their email address then you can use `fetchSignInMethods` and it will automatically show with the above alert. I've not got the chance to link the user who chose to keep their identity secret, but I will update my answer with that very soon.

I've tried to be as elaborative as possible, please do let me know if you have any queries.

[image: Once Email, Facebook and Google are linked]

Comment: In both examples, errors may occur when the user decides not to use his email for account creation. Right now I'm trying to deal with this..
errors can also occur for my example

Comment: It seems that when the user logs in without identity (without email) and subsequently decides to log in showing his identity with the same provider, the link does not work and returns this error `[ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED] - User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider`

This seems to happen even if the user doesn't need to link to another provider @bojeil

Comment: @kAiN To clarify things, let's do a test. Currently, I do not have any `Apple Sign Ins`. You can test this: Signup a user with an `email` and then use the same email for `Apple Sign In` and share the email and see what `fetchSignInMethod` does, it will throw the linking error I know. Once this first test is done, delete user and repeat the same while hiding your email(Not sharing email), let's see what `fetchSignInProvider` method does then, will it throw a linking error or not that is the actual question.

Comment: I confirm that if we use an Apple user with hidden email the `fetchSignInMethods` method is not taken into consideration in any case ..

So are we forced to let the user create another different account when he is not using his email?

Comment: @What did the `fetchSignInMethods` give? Did it give an error, did it give 0 provider?

Comment: the `fetchSignInMethods` **return error = nil** and **provider = nil**
What should we do if the user (after creating his account with privaterelay.appleid.com) decides to log in with Apple again showing his email instead?

Comment: NO sorry ... returns error = nil and provider = nil ... sorry ..

Comment: Instead if we created an Apple user with hidden email and we delete the **"apps that use Apple Sign In"** in iCloud Setting of Device to access the visible email with apple sign in, the `fetchSignInMethods` finds the google account but cannot complete the link

Comment: @kAiN Why? How many providers does it return in `fetchSignInMethod`?

Comment: The fetchSignInMethods find Google provider but not complete the link ... it’s strange

Comment: This is the error received when trying to link an existing provider to the Apple provider with Visible Email. Previously an Apple Account with Hidden Email had been created

`[ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED] - User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider`

Comment: i have Ask a new Question For This! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008490/issue-firebase-authentication-apple-sign-in-with-hidden-email