# Issue Firebase Authentication - Apple Sign In with Hidden Email

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working with `Firebase` to authenticate my users in my **iOS** app

**I noticed a problem with the Apple provider.**

---

I'll explain better the steps that a user could do:

1. Create an **Apple Provider** Account with **Hidden Email**. Your Firebase account will be created like this

[image]

---

2. Create an account with **Google**. We will have **2 different accounts** created

[image]

---

3. The user decides to delete my app from the **iCloud settings** (*on his device*) from those that access with Apple

[image]

---

4. The user creates a **new account with Apple** provider, but this time he shows the email

[image]

---

5. When the authentication flow begins, through the `Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email)` method, find the **Google** account previously created and try the **link with Google**.

---

6. The link does not complete and returns this error:

> [ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED] - User can only be linked to one
>   identity for the given provider.

---

This is the problem I'm having when a user decides to use an **Apple account with hidden Email**

**How can we manage authentications with Apple on Firebase in this case?**

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Are you saying there is an existing Google account for this email? How do you know the user's email ahead of time? You can't tell the email until they try to sign in with Google or Apple.

Comment: @bojeil I'm making the attempts .. currently my app is not yet on the app store. I created an apple user with hidden email (the email is my Apple ID) ... then I created a google user with my email (it is the same as the Apple ID) .. after creating the two accounts , I deleted my app from those that use apple to authenticate from iCloud setting and I tried again to create an apple user leaving my email visible .. When I create the new Apple user with visible email firebase it gives me the error I described.

Comment: Apple users are considered verified. The last Apple sign in with the visible email should automatically merge with the existing Google account of the same email.

Comment: @bojeil I noticed that the two accounts do not link to each other ... I mean that in the firebase the google user does not have the apple logo next to the google one .. so I think the two accounts are not linked

Comment: I think you should tell the user to sign in because an account already exists with the email. Even though he has never created an account using Apple it should log into his existing Firebase auth account.

Comment: Hello man, glad to see Italians doing great stuff!
I have a similar problem (in my case Firebase doesn't update the email but keeps the old forwarding one). Were you able to solve btw?